# LinearLayout dividers deos not show up using holoeverywhere

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-holo-everywhere, divider

I have this xml file that should display a `divider` between the `TextView` and the `Button`.

I am using `holoeverywhere` library .

using this code the divide does not show

```
    <org.holoeverywhere.widget.LinearLayout
                         xmlns:holo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/topcontainer"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        holo:divider="?attr/dividerVertical"
                        holo:dividerPadding="8dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        holo:showDividers="middle" >

                        <org.holoeverywhere.widget.TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView6"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/str1" />

      <org.holoeverywhere.widget.Button
                            android:id="@+id/add"
                            style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:text="ADD" />
</org.holoeverywhere.widget.LinearLayout>
```

now the problem is with these attributes in the `LinearLayout`

```
holo:divider="?attr/dividerVertical"
holo:dividerPadding="8dp"
holo:showDividers="middle"
```

if i change the `namespace` on these attributes to `android` like this it works and the divider is shown.

any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Use the `android` namespace. That should be good.

As I see the source code of the `attrs` [here](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/blob/master/library/res/values/attrs.xml).

```
<declare-styleable name="LinearLayout">
        <attr name="android:baselineAligned"/>
        <attr name="android:baselineAlignedChildIndex"/>
        <attr name="android:divider"/>
        <attr name="android:dividerPadding"/>
        <attr name="android:gravity"/>
        <attr name="android:measureWithLargestChild"/>
        <attr name="android:orientation"/>
        <attr name="android:showDividers"/>
        <attr name="android:weightSum"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

The custom attrs seems to be defined with the android namespace.

Also, looking at the source of `org.holoeverywhere.widget.LinearLayout` [here](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/blob/master/library/src/org/holoeverywhere/widget/LinearLayout.java) you will see that the `LinearLayout` class is using the above defined `attrs` like LinearLayout_**android**_baselineAlignedChildIndex and hence works with the `android namespace`.